# Newbie Question about crypto wallet development

Tags: web3js, tokens, ethers.js

I'm a senior developer but newbie in web3 development

I'm looking to build a crypto wallet functionalities into my NodeJS server.

Would like to understand some point related to the tokens

How to get the list of tokens for a coin address with their balances

for example

that address : https://bscscan.com/address/0xe934d2c5be5db0295a4de3177762a9e8c74ae4f4

it has

> 21311 Cake
>
> 0.002 NGM

It looks there's no direct way to do that in Web3 or EthersJS

And I don't prefer to use external service like Moralis or BSCScan.com,
to save costs and support more chains without limits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy way to do it, what wallets like metamask do is that they'd check for a token balance and display it only when instructed to through the `wallet_watchAsset` method.

The way moralis or other API providers do that is by indexing the whole chain on their end, constructing a users balances database from all the `Transfer` events they find, and then when requested, checking users tokens against their own database, not against the chain, for faster and cheaper response.

I assume you could do that, but i don't think that'd be useful (and also it relies too much on a centralized entity not failing, imo). I'd suggest you stick to wallet_watchAsset or maybe have a list of tokens to look for by default (like, very popular tokens like usdt, aave, etc.) and just let the user add tokens if they want to

Comment: It really help, thanks Foxxxey